# Downsides of Apache portable runtime (APR) for Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, apr

I have been reading blogs and everywhere i only see the positives sides of using APR modules. But i am wondering are there any downsides of using it as its by default not shipped in tomcat package ?

Comment: Can you name a particular module and maybe someone can provide a better answer. There could be known issues/limitations with a specific module when you use with APR vs. when you use without.